# float[] 16 bits to byte[]

Tags: java, android

I have converted `byte[]` into `float[]` using this way:

```
public voidcheckingActivity(byte[] data, int numbytes) {
    size_data_proc = data.length / 2;
    float[] data_proc = new float[size_data_proc];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
        data_proc[i / 2] = data[i] | (data[i + 1] << 8);
    }
}
```

Because I am reading audio sample 16 bits.

Now I need the inverse process: I have a `float[]` which contains 16 bits samples and I want to convert in `byte[]`.

So, I suppose that I have to create a `byte[]` that size is `float*2` but how can I obtain the value of `byte`s ?

thanks

EDIT:

To be more preccis, i capture blocks of 200 ms of 16 bits audio. to process these blocks i need samples in float, so i have to combine 2 bytes of byte array in one element of float.
This process is code below.

And after process i need reconvert my float samples in bytes, so i need that each elements of float[] is in two elemets of byte[]

Comment: I was trying to understand your code but to no avail. What is `size_data_proc` for example? `float` uses 32bit in java, `byte` 8 so you can combine 4 `byte`s to the space of 1 `float` not just 2 as you do.

Comment: tha main idea is that in data i have 200 ms of 16 bits audio samples, then i need combine 2 bytes (a real sample) in which elements of my float array

Comment: and finally, when i process this float[] i need reconvert in byte[], so i need combine each elements of the array in two elements of byte[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio data in Android is typically little endian 16-bit signed PCM. I **think** you may have the byte order reversed (but it's been a while). Also, if you don't mask off the least significant byte you will get spurious audio artifacts because of automatic sign extension.

With fixes for those, your code should probably look something like this:

```
public void checkingActivity(byte[] data {
    float[] data_proc = new float[size_data_proc];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
        data_proc[i / 2] = (int) (data[i] << 8) | (int) (data[i+1] & 0x00ff);
    }
```

}

The inverse operation then looks like:

```
public byte[] floatArrayToBytes(float[] data {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[data.length * 2];
    float  scale = 1.0f;
    int    ix    = 0;

    for (float sample: data) {
        int value = sample * scale;
        bytes[ix++] = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 0x00ff);
        bytes[ix++] = (byte) (value & 0x00ff);
    }

 return bytes;
```

}

You might want to normalise your audio to a range of -1.0f to +1.0f if you're working with float values.

Comment: i try this solution but seems that is the correct solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.nio.ByteBuffer` class :

```
public static byte[] float2ByteArray(final float[] value) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * value.length);// a float has 4 bytes
    for (float f : value) {
        buffer.putFloat(f);
    }
    return buffer.array();
}
```